# tm_bubbles to display zero count data

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to visulaise count data using tmap for the first time. Zero counts are informative and need to be displayed.

I have the following code:

```
Long<- c(149.942, 149.93583, 149.96217, 149.963, 149.96833, 
149.97233)
Lat <- c(-36.919, -36.8345, -36.92367, -36.81117, -36.97183, 
-36.96033)
count <- c(0, 0, 107, 0, 0, 20)
da<-data.frame(Long, Lat, count)
locations_sf3 <- st_as_sf(da, coords = c("Long", "Lat"))
ns<-locations_sf3
tm_shape(ns) +
 tm_bubbles(col = "gold", size = "count")+
tm_legend(outside = TRUE)
```

[image]

However, tm_bubbles removes the zeros. I have coded this in ggplot and displayed zeros but wanted to move to the more elegant tmap. the ggplot code:

```
ggplot(aes(longitude, latitude, size = sum))+
 annotation_map(map_data("world"))+
  geom_point(col="red",pch=16)+
 coord_quickmap()
```

Giving:

[image]

Any help to get this working in tmap would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you need to convert `0` to `1` in order to allow tmap to show the "zero" data points.

Comment: thanks, that seems to get the zero count data on the map. Any hints on customising the legend to display the size of the zero (or 1) counts would be appreciated

Comment: Something like this for your custom legend? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890762/how-to-manipulate-tmap-legend